# jQuery UI Dialog using a form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, dialog

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="button-to-delete">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
</form>

<div class="hidden-dialog" title="Delete product">
    <p>Are you sure that you want to delete thi product?</p>
    <p>Green Lantern T-Shirt</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden-dialog   { display: none; }​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dialog = $('form.button-to-delete + div.hidden-dialog').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Yes!' : {
                class: 'btn btn-danger',
                text: 'Yes!',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).prev('form.button-to-delete').submit(true);
                }
            },
            'No!' : {
                class: 'btn',
                text: 'No!',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('form.button-to-delete').submit(function() {
        var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");

        dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

And here is the jsFiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/mdJZ8/1/

So when I click the form button, a jQuery UI Dialog appears with a message and two buttons: "Yes!" and "No!".
The "No!" button works normally. The "Yes!" button on the other hand doesn't. It's supposed to submit the form
and it doesn't. I suspect that the problem is coming from the `return false` statement. However, if I remove
the statement, the Dialog appears for a split second and the form gets submitted without giving the chance to the
user to choose an option. How can I fix this code so that it only submits the form if the user clicks the "Yes!" button please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. What I needed to do is use the following statement:

```
$('form.button-to-delete').unbind("submit").submit();
```

Here is the full jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var dialog = $('form.button-to-delete + div.hidden-dialog').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Yes!' : {
                class: 'btn btn-danger',
                text: 'Yes!',
                click: function () {
                    $('form.button-to-delete').unbind("submit").submit();
                }
            },
            'No!' : {
                class: 'btn',
                text: 'No!',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
        }
    });

    $('form.button-to-delete').submit(function() {
        var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");

        dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work on my app. The dialog doesn't even appear when I click the button. No matter how "messy" the one line of code is, it just works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could replace JS with :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var dialog = $('form.button-to-delete + div.hidden-dialog').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Yes!' : {
            class: 'btn btn-danger',
            text: 'Yes!',
            click: function () {
                return true;
            }
        },
        'No!' : {
            class: 'btn',
            text: 'No!',
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});

$('form.button-to-delete').submit(function() {
    var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");

    return dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

});

Comment: Nope..still not working. Now it's a different problem though: the dialog opens for a split second and then the form is submitted without giving the user then change to select an option...

Comment: sorry, realize an var can't return true or false. Should redo it to a function call instead, but Francois Wahl above already solved it..

Answer (score 0):

How about keying off of the visibility of the modal dialog?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dialog = $('form.button-to-delete + div.hidden-dialog').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Yes!' : {
            class: 'btn btn-danger',
            text: 'Yes!',
            click: function () {
                $(this).prev('form.button-to-delete').submit();
            }
        },
        'No!' : {
            class: 'btn',
            text: 'No!',
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }
  });

  $('form.button-to-delete').submit(function() {
    var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");

    if($('div.hidden-dialog').is(':visible')) {
      return true;
    }

    dialog.dialog('open');
    return false;

  }); 
});
```